# Center a button using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to center the vote button in below script ?

```
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6352993.js"></script>
    <noscript><a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/6352993/">This is very long test question to test how polldaddy handles questions that exceed that normal length............ yes a very long question indeed..............</a></noscript>​
```

The button is styled with class : 'pds-vote-button'

Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/25LjE/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BY USING JQUERY:**

```
$('.pds-votebutton-outer').css('text-align','center');
```

**DEMO USING JQUERY** http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/25LjE/29/

**OR BY USING CSS:**

```
.pds-votebutton-outer {
    text-align:center;
}
```

**DEMO USING CSS** http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/25LjE/33/

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$('#example td:nth-col(1)').textAlign(',');
```

where your class to be replaced with id specified.